# (Android) Force Opera Mini to open links in native browser?

Tags: android, opera-mini

Is there any way to force Opera Mini for Android to open a link to the webpage in a native browser(just like it opens attachment files)?

Comment: You'll want to take this over to the Android stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

No, Opera Mini does not broadcast intents in that way.